# angularjs replace entire div when on click

Tags: angularjs

Let say I have a

```
<div class="leftbar">
 <div class="leftcontent>
 This is leftbar
 </div>
</div>
```

and a right bar

```
<div class="rightbar">
 <div class="rightcontent">     
 This is rightbar
 <button>I have a button here</button>
 </div>
</div>
```

When the rightbar button is clicked, I want to get data from wherever then replace
entire `div left content` and `div right content` with `new div with {{data}}`

I haven't try anything yet because I have no idea how to start this.
And I also know we can do this by using share service and pass value to other `ng-controller` but my problem is how to replace the entire div without navigate to another url.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

ngShow is useful for the kind of swapping you're describing.

```
<div class="leftbar">
    <div class="leftcontent" ng-show="!clicked">
        This is leftbar
    </div>
    <div class="newleftcontent" ng-show="clicked">
        {{data}}
    </div>
</div>

<div class="rightbar">
    <div class="rightcontent">     
        This is rightbar
        <button ng-click="clicked=1">I have a button here</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

You hinted that these two areas might be run by separate controllers. If that's the case, then, yes, you ought to create a service that handles the values of `clicked` and `data` so that it can be injected and shared between the two controllers. You might want to clarify your question to get more specific help.